# React native navigation 5 slow render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I am using Expo and react native navigation 5 in my app. The problem I am having is that in the first render, in development mode, the tab icons are showed slow, I mean, they appear after a little delay. Is this a bug? Has anyone experienced this? Will this dissapear in production mode?

In App.js I have a conditional render (the splash screen or the navigator), but I suppose this is not the problem. Why would it be? It's just a conditional render.

Conditional render in App.js:

```
render() {
    const { isLoading, missingPermissions } = this.state;

    /*
      The main content of tha app will be rendered only when:
        1) All custom fonts are loaded
        2) The user auth state is checked

      Pd: All these actions are handled by the Splash screen
    */

    return (
      <SafeAreaView
        style={styles.container}
        forceInset={{ top: "never", bottom: "never" }}
      >
        <StatusBarPlaceholder />
        {!isLoading ? (
            <AppContent missingPermissions={missingPermissions} />
        ) : (
            <SplashScreen handleIsLoading={this.handleIsLoading} />
        )}
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

Pd: handleIsLoading just set the App.js isLoading state to false, and is invoked in the SplashScreen, after loading all fonts.

One solution that I have found is to do:

```
render() {
    const { isLoading, missingPermissions } = this.state;

    /*
      The main content of tha app will be rendered only when:
        1) All custom fonts are loaded
        2) The user auth state is checked

      Pd: All these actions are handled by the Splash screen
    */

    return (
      <SafeAreaView
        style={styles.container}
        forceInset={{ top: "never", bottom: "never" }}
      >
        <StatusBarPlaceholder />
        {!isLoading && <AppContent missingPermissions={missingPermissions} />}
        <SplashScreen handleIsLoading={this.handleIsLoading} />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

But not really what I want.

**THE CODE OF AppContent:**

```
function AppContent({ missingPermissions }) {
  if (missingPermissions.length)
    return <PermissionsController permission={missingPermissions[0]} />;

  return (
    <View style={styles.appContainer}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <RootNavigator />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please provide a code and maybe a video where the delay persists?!

Comment: Done. (Not the video because I think is unnecesary. Imagine just a delay of a few seconds before showing the tab navigator icons)